# I need help on this project for my friend

Tags: javascript, html

so whenever i click the thing it only gives my 2 of my possible alerts how do i get it to go do all 3 heres my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>    
<body>
    <img src="http://www.buildabear.com/ProductImages/BABW_US/XL/17525Alt1x.jpg" alt="hi" witdh="200px" height="200px" onclick="thisFunction()" style="left: 50%; margin: auto">        
    <p>I am Fat</p>
    <script>    
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

        var thisFunction = function() {
            var ranInt = Math.round(Math.random(0, 2));

            if (ranInt == 0) {
                alert("Peacebear exp1l");
            } else if (ranInt == 1) {
                 alert("Peacebear ex2");
            } else if (ranInt == 2) {
                alert("Peacebear ex3");
            }
        };    

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever read the `Math.random()` documentation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.random() doesn't take any parameters. It just generates a number between 0 and 1. So round function produces either 0 if number is < 0.5 or 1 if > 0.5.
In order to generate a random number between 0 and 2 do like this:

```
var ranInt = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
```